# Laravel 4 on PHP built-in web server (CGI) instead of Apache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cgi

I am trying to run laravel4 on a service that cannot use Apache or nginx.
everything is good till I wanted to use Routes on my project.
I've tried using `/index.php/...` on the URL but could not make this work.
is there any way to force laravel not to use .htaccess file or any ways to use raw PHP routing?

Comment: Question is not clear. What doesn't work exactly? PHP's built-in server is not meant for production. What server will you use?

Comment: Laravel Routings does not work.
for example i can not access,  127.0.0.1/public/user/login or 127.0.0.1/public/index.php/user/login

Comment: Iam using PHPDesktop to develop some php app https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/

Comment: So `./artisan serve` doesn't work? Do you have all permissions set correctly on your files and folders?

Comment: What about the 127.0.0.1/index.php/user/login? Is phpdesktop serving from the public directory, or from the project's root folder?

Comment: phpdesktop has a config to make it run from public/ directory.
the point is that i can see the login page i've made (index controller) , but when i click the "login" button which would lead user to the certain routing, it fails.

Comment: Yah Ya is asking on how to disable pretty urls, as the web server he is using doesn't support url rewrite patterns. PS. Php Desktop is hosting a Mongoose web server.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak 
Yup,tnx. thats the main question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the "application.url" option in one of configuration files, probably in app/config/application.php or application/config/application.php:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4cb904f44d24f856ec9c1040d2198ed8f009723b/application/config/application.php

Set it to `http://127.0.0.1:54007/index.php`. Now when laravel creates url it will use this as a root and the final urls should be like `http://127.0.0.1:54007/index.php/account/signin`.

Also you need to modify PHP Desktop settings so that it uses a fixed port. Edit settings.json file and set it like this:

```
"web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 54007],
```

In laravel's .htaccess I've found this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So it should work fine to add "/index.php" to root url, because this is what apache's mod_rewrite does.

If something doesn't work, take a look at some other files named "url.php", "uri.php".

Let us know if that works.

**EDIT.**
You may also try setting root url to "index.php", without the "http://". This way it wouldn't be required to set a fixed web server port.

**UPDATE**
There was a bug in Mongoose web server in PHP Desktop, that prevented urls like "index.php/company/5" from working properly. See the __fix_mongoose_env_variables() php function in Issue 137 that fixes it:

https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/issues/detail?id=137