# how to run laravel application in phpdesktop application?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, phpdesktop

I have downloaded phpdesktop application and copied working laravel application into the phpdesktop www directory. Also enabled the necessary extension in php-ini file inside phpdesktop application.

Index page of the application is working properly. but I am getting the following error messages when accessing other pages.

Error 404: Not Found
File not found

phpdesktop doesn't have apache server to enable mod_rewrite to solve this issue. How to overcome this issue? Plz guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 on PHP built-in web server (CGI) instead of Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517695/laravel-4-on-php-built-in-web-server-cgi-instead-of-apache)

Answer (score 0):

for laravel, you need to change www_directory, point it towards `"www/public"`

```
"web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 0],
    "www_directory": "www/public",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/pretty-urls.php",
    "hide_files": []
},
```

Answer (score 0):

phpDesktop 57 is currently using php 7.1.x if you want to run latest version of the laravel then just download the required version of php from official website and delete all the files and folder from the php folder inside phpDesktop except php.ini and put all the downloaded files and folder of php in php directory then you will be able to run laravel application inside phpDesktop.

you can have a reference from here: [Just Check this article](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-desktop-application)